# Move document from "my" site to public library in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm actually testing Sharepoint 2013, primarily for document management and sharing with colleagues.
When working on a file (e.g. word), I'd like to keep it private until it's ready for public use. Therefore, I'd start working in my private website (aka /my) and move it to the public document library as soon as it's ready.
How can I do this? I can't find any "move"-command in the library. (moving it via explorer does not work between different sites).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drag and drop Windows Explorer (not Internet Explorer), if not it is likely that you need to move the domain into either the IE trusted or intranet security zone.

You cannot do this directly in Internet Explorer because the libraries are in different sites which are kept very independent by Microsoft.

To do what you want though would probably be better done through the use of check-out/in. Create the document in the target library but don't check it in until you are ready for others to see it. This happens automatically if you set "require check out" in the library. Then, even if you upload documents via Windows Explorer, no-one will be able to see it until you (or an admin by override) checks it in for the first time.

This also has the advantage that you can make further amendments by checking out the document. Nobody can see your amendments until it is checked back in.

This also has the advantage of retaining full version history that you would otherwise loose by moving the document between sites.

Comment: When trying to move the file via windows explorer, it throws an error telling that the source file can't be read.